# Change app background color in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, styling

I'm trying to change the color of the background in my React Native app, from grey to white. I'm using *react-navigation* to make a `TabNavigator` after I render it. I tried to put this `TabNavigator` in a view and set `backgroundColor` but all screen became white. How can I solve this?

**index.js**

```js
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}}>
                <Tabs />
            </View>
        )
      }
```

**Tabs**

```js
    const Tabs = TabNavigator(
      {
        Home: {
          screen: HomeStack,
          navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Acasa',
          },
        },
        ...
        Account: {
          screen: AccountScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Contul meu',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        tabBarComponent: props => <FooterNavigation {...props} />,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
      },
    );
```

**Home Screen**

```js
    render() {
        const {
          data, refreshing, loading, error,
        } = this.state;
    
        return (
          <ScrollView>
            <Container>
              {error && <Text>Error</Text>}
              {loading && <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />}
    
              <List>
                <FlatList
                  data={data}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <ListItem onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Item', item)}>
                      <Item data={item} />
                    </ListItem>
                  )}
                  // ID from database as a key
                  keyExtractor={item => item.title}
                  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                  ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
                  ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                  refreshing={refreshing}
                  onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
                  onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
                  onEndReachedThreshold={0}
                />
              </List>
            </Container>
          </ScrollView>
        );
      }
```

Comment: `<View style={{backgroundColor : "white"}}> <Tabs/> </View>`

Comment: I have tried, and all screen became white
https://imgur.com/a/faBqkLt

Comment: Can you show the home screen code?

Comment: where you have added background color : white ?

Comment: I tried in index.js, where is <Tabs />, i did something like <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}}><Tabs /></View>, but it made my screen all white, not only background

Comment: what's your expected result?

Comment: Well, by default, on ios device, for example, is a gray background, I want to change it to white

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've solved my problem, it was caused by `StackNavigator`. To solve it , just add some extra options

```js
const HomeStack = StackNavigator(
      {
        Home: {
          screen: HomeScreen,
        },
        Item: {
          screen: ItemScreen,
          navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: `${navigation.state.params.title}`,
          }),
        },
      },
      **
      {
        headerMode: 'screen',
        cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' },
      },
      **
    );
```

Answer (score 30):

For React Navigation 6,

```
<Stack.Navigator  screenOptions={{
     contentStyle:{
       backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF'
     }
  }}  initialRouteName="Home">
```

Comment: Thanks, the above options didn't work for me

Answer (score 26):

For React Navigation 5 and above

```js
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName='dashboard'
        screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: { elevation: 0 },
            cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' }
        }}
    >
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

For React Navigation 4 and earlier

```js
    const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
        Home: {
            screen: HomeScreen,
        },
    },
    {
        headerMode: 'screen',
        cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
    },
    );
```

Answer (score 11):

Edit your View tag like this,

```
  <View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor: '#6ED4C8'}}></View>
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct prop to be set is `sceneContainerStyle`:

```
  <BottomTab.Navigator
    ...
    sceneContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
  >
      ...
   </BottomTab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 5):

For React Navigation 6 -->

Stack Navigator:

```js
<Stack.Navigator 
    screenOptions={{ contentStyle: {backgroundColor: 'white'} }}
>
```

Tab Navigator:

```js
<Tab.Navigator
    sceneContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
    ...
>
```

Answer (score 4):

The following will no longer work due to deprecation.

```
 const HomeStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Item: {
      screen: ItemScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: `${navigation.state.params.title}`,
      }),
    },
  },
  **
  {
    headerMode: 'screen',
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' },
  },
  **
);
```

You now have to use defaultNavigationOptions (see below).

```
 const HomeStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Item: {
      screen: ItemScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: `${navigation.state.params.title}`,
      }),
    },
  },
  **
  {
    headerMode: 'screen',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' },
    },
  },
  **
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Set in view that's where you want to set background colour

```js
view: {
  backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' 
}
```